# WP7 Listbox Automatic Scrolling Using MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm

I have a ListBox that I've bound to a List of ordered times. When the ListBox loads I'd like to show the item that will be next at the top of the screen.

Is there a way to do this in WP7 using MVVM? I've looked around and there seems to be solutions for WPF but I can't seem to find any for WP7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. Implement an attached property that calls [`ScrollIntoView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) when the value changes (this method seems cleaner, but I'm not 100% sure it will work on WP7's Silverlight 3 runtime)
2. Implement it as a [Blend Bahavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726531%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) that supports a bindable property (the ButtonCommand behavior in [P&P's WP7 Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490765.aspx) has some trickery to achieve this on SL3) that calls ScrollIntoView when the bound value changes.

It's worth noting that `ScrollIntoView` only ensures the value is visible, not that it's at the top.

Comment: Unfortunately I took the easy way and didn't implement this in MVVM. If I have a change of heart and decide to implement using MVVM I'll try this out and mark as answer if it works.

Thanks Richard